# Automatic AOV shader pass setup for geometry buffer

Tags: python, cycles-render-engine, shaders, render-passes

Is there a way to create AOVs that affects all materials in the scene? I can successfully create an AOV shader pass that outputs world positions of the object material is on:

[image]

This gives me correct result, which I save to a separate file using composition. The problem is, that this is the only object that will be considered in the shader pass, rest of the image is empty.

So I would like have this shader pass for all of the materials in the scene. Am I coming at this wrong, or should I apply AOV Output to all 150 materials in my case? If the latter is correct, can this be done in python blender API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override all materials in the scene as in the figure below. This is what I did in our paper ["Fast Synthetic LiDAR Rendering via Spherical UV Unwrapping of Equirectangular Z-Buffer Images"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04345). It is worth looking into material management addons.

[image]

Comment: Works as described, thank you!